# How to make key colour black in Gnuplot

Tags: colors, key, gnuplot, palette

How can I make the key "symbols" black in colour when using palettes?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot control this directly, here a workaround:

```
plot 'MOD1.dat' u 2:3:1 w p pt 7 ps 2 lt black, \
'MOD1.dat' u 2:3:1 w p pt 7 ps 2 lt palette notitle
```

So, we first plot the data without legend in black, then plot the data points but no legend. The nice thing about this approach is that there is no need to fix the x or y range.

Answer (score 4):

I would just create a dummy line and use `notitle` on the real lines. Something like

```
set yrange[0:1]
plot "realdata1.data" u 1:2 w linespoints lt 1 notitle   , \
     "realdata2.data" u 1:2 w linespoints lt 2 notitle   , \
     1/0 w linespoints lt 1 lc rgb 'black' title 'Model1', \
     1/0 w linespoints lt 1 lc rgb 'black' title 'Model2'
```

Then replace `lt 1` with whatever you have used for style in your current plot. Note that you'll need to use `set yrange` for gnuplot to accept the dummy curve